# Varnish to Vsites on Apache servers

Tags: virtualhost, redirect, varnish, local-area-network

Can anyone advise of a VCL conf that redirects (inside LAN & LAN DNS) to get to multiple named hosts?

i.e.
http://x.ourdomain.com = IP of Varnish Server = redirects to LAN host (i.e. 10.0.5.1)
http://y.ourdomain.com = IP of Varnish Server = redirects to LAN host (i.e. 10.0.5.5)
etc

I have been at varnish for some 5 hours and a small amount of my brain has already died.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub vcl_recv {
  set req.backend = default_backend;
  if ( req.http.Host == "x.ourdomain.com" ) {
    set req.backend = x_backend;
  }
  if ( req.http.Host == "y.ourdomain.com" ) {
    set req.backend = y_backend;
  }
}
```

Unless you're looking for actual *redirects*, in which case:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if ( req.http.Host == "x.ourdomain.com" ) {
    error 750 "http://10.0.5.1" + req.url;
  }
  if ( req.http.Host == "y.ourdomain.com" ) {
    error 750 "http://10.0.5.5" + req.url;
  }
}

sub vcl_error {
  if ( obj.status == 750 ) {
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    set obj.status = "302";
    set obj.response = "Found";
    return(deliver);
  }
}
```